# Fine tuning mouse acceleration of a logitech mouse on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, mouse, logitech-mouse

I have a logitech mouse and want to fine tune the acceleration. I have Logitech's Setpoint software installed and the settings for Acceleration allow me to set:

- off
- low
- medium
- high

But even **low** is already too high for me. Is there a way to fine tune it? Perhaps some registry setting or some sort of program?

Comment: Some Logitech mice have a button behind the scroll wheel to quickly change acceleration/scroll speeds. Is this the case with your mouse?

Comment: @Robotnik no there is no such button